# Применить макрос Excel сразу к нескольким ячейкам

Tags: excel, vba, макросы

Написал макрос в VBA Excel, для ускорения работы. Но мне всё равно надо выполнить 3600 таких операций, для каждой ячейки (нажимать cntrl + t). Можно ли выполнить сразу для всех ячеек этот макрос в автоматическом режиме?

Comment: Пробовали? Помогло? Вообще не о том пишу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть операции с массивами.

1. выделяете массив ячеек
2. вводите формулу относительно другого массива или массивов. Они должны быть того же размера.
3. подтверждаете <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: В моём случае это немного не то. Я решил вопрос написанием другого макроса, который выполняет первый в автоматическом режиме.

Comment: @АлександрЛазневой: так опубликуйте ответ!